# how to filter out contact data from payload

Tags: jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I have created a webhook from Mailchimp to AWS Step Functions. The step machine gets the following input via the webhook when a new contact has signed up:

`"type=subscribe&fired_at=2023-05-02+15%3A57%3A33&data%5Bid%5D=9831e7c72b&data%5Bemail%5D=moritz.richarz%2B12%40gmail.com&data%5Bemail_type%5D=html&data%5Bip_opt%5D=89.1.210.213&data%5Bweb_id%5D=487434089&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BEMAIL%5D=moritz.richarz%2B12%40gmail.com&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BFNAME%5D=M&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BLNAME%5D=Richarz&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BADDRESS%5D=&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BPHONE%5D=&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BBIRTHDAY%5D=&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BMMERGE6%5D=&data%5Blist_id%5D=176a98d2e8"`

I want to filter out the email-address, first and last name in order to process these data in further steps in the step machine.

I can't find a way with the in- and and output configurations withing Step Functions, because they the payload does not have a common JSON structure that I could use jsonpath with if I see this correctly.

I got the tip from someone to use https://middy.js.org/docs/middlewares/intro in some way, but being the noob that I am I could not find out what exactly could help me here. I looked at "https://middy.js.org/docs/middlewares/http-json-body-parser" because it sounded suitable, but did not really get the example.

Comment: You require some sort of compute task to parse the string.  A Lambda function is a natural choice.  Write a function to decode the URI query components and parse them, perhaps with regex.  The Lambda function would output the parsed components as JSON to the next task.